# Search suggestion as I type Excel Data Validation list with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a search as I type in Excel file where I have a List of products (on one worksheet) and Proforma Invoice on another. Proforma contains Data Validation drop-downs in the cells to select products from the drop down menu. As my list contains more than 6000 items it is very difficult to search through all of them to find the right item manually.

I have tried the following:

```
  Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lType As Long

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
lType = Target.Validation.Type
On Error GoTo 0

If lType = 3 Then
  With Sheets("Lists")
    .Range("CritProd").Cells(2, 1).Value = _
        "*" & Target.Offset(0, -1).Value & "*"
    .Range("ProdList").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=.Range("CritProd"), _
        CopyToRange:=.Range("extProd"), _
        Unique:=False
  End With
End If

End Sub
```

where `CritProd` is  `=Lists!B:B` that contains all of my product names, `ProdList` is `=OFFSET(Lists!$I$1,0,0,COUNTA(Lists!$I:$I),1)` and `extProd` is =Lists!$I$1.

I have also found a YouTube video that explains how to do it without VBA, but it only works with one cell and in my case there may be more than just one cell.

Comment: Maybe is the "SelectionChange" a wrong event. Take a look at this ansewr please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: Thanks, I have seen it already, but it did not help to do what I need

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26304592/2832561 this solution will allow filtering your list of choices character by character

Comment: If you don't have a lot of Data Validated fields and can use ComboBoxes instead I provided a solution with the search-suggestion-as-you-type in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32575926/4914662)

Comment: @paulbica, it is a great suggestion, but ComboBoxes are not the best solution in my situation as there may be a need to add more rows in my Proforma Invoice to accommodate more products, so this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I've also created a dynamic searchable data validation list on an invoice template to bring data from the products page to the home page. The data validation lists we create with a formula and a small VBA code can be searched.

Formula for cell A19 : `=OFFSET(Product!$A$2,MATCH($A19&"*",Products_1,0)-1,,COUNTIF(Products_1,$A19&"*"),)`

[Source to view sample file](https://eksi30.com/excel-search-in-data-validation-list-searchable-drop-down-list/)

[image]